# View Flipper Android

Tags: android, animation

I have few images to animate in flipper , when next button is pressed the next image should come from right side and current image should go out from left side , similarly if back is pressed previous should come from right side and current image should go out. I want left in right out, left out right in animation , keep in mind heap size as well, any body has solution?
I used this code

```
 nbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (current_shown_index < list.length - 1) {
            current_shown_index++;           
            bkbtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_flipper_item, null);
            ImageView iv = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_flipper_item);                 
            iv.setImageResource(list[current_shown_index]);
            Log.v("count", vFlipper.getChildCount() + "flipper length");
            if (vFlipper.getChildCount() == 3) {                       
                vFlipper.removeViewAt(0);
            }
            vFlipper.addView(view);               
            vFlipper.setInAnimation(inFromRightAnimation());      
            vFlipper.setOutAnimation(outToLeftAnimation());
            vFlipper.showNext();
        }
    }
});
bkbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {                
        if (current_shown_index > 0) {                  
            int diff = 2;
            if (vFlipper.getChildCount() == 3 ){          
                vFlipper.removeViewAt(2);                   
            }
            View viewb = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_flipper_item, null);
            ImageView iv = (ImageView) viewb.findViewById(R.id.iv_flipper_item);
            if(current_shown_index == 1 ){
                diff = 1;
            }else{                     
                iv.setImageResource(list[current_shown_index-diff ]);
            }
            vFlipper.addView(viewb, 0);
            current_shown_index--;
        }else{                 
            bkbtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }             
        vFlipper.setInAnimation(inFromLeftAnimation());        
        vFlipper.setOutAnimation(outToRightAnimation());
        vFlipper.showPrevious();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you a starting pointer:

```
final Animation outToLeft = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, android.R.anim.slide_out_right); 
final Animation inFromRight = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, android.R.anim.slide_in_left);

final Animation outToRight = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, android.R.anim.slide_out_left); 
final Animation inFromLeft = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, android.R.anim.slide_in_right);
```

Now use these with `setInAnimation` and `setOutAnimation` in your `ViewFlipper`.

Answer (score 0):

For achieving in and out animation in ViewFlipper, you can use `setInAnimation()` and `setOutAnimation()` methods.

**For example:**

```
  viewFlipper.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
                            mContext, android.R.anim.slide_in_right));
    viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
                            mContext, android.R.anim.slide_out_right));

   /* Where - mContext is Context object     
   */
```

Comment: Animations are working well , but main problem is memory i have to remove the view as heap size increase after a few images , so i want to keep max of 3 view at a time in flipper , rest i want to remove, this working well on next button but when i click back button then it creats problem it changes the images.

Comment: @atiq_se Ok, I see.  In this case, why not use `ViewPager` instead?  With it, you never keep more than 2 views in memory: the one sliding out and the one sliding in.  You create those views on the fly as and when needed, you automatically get slide-in-out left/right animation and, as an added bonus, you get finger gesture recognition for navigating through images.

Answer (score 0):

ViewSwitcher can handle this for you, [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pGLabREOodc&feature=relmfu) a view switcher in action

You can also find here an [example](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mGwG8-chUEM) with source code attached to it